# ADB re-recognise device

Tags: android, adb

Usually, I starts the ADB server daemon and connect my physical test device, and then the device would be recognised as I run "adb devices". If for some reason we "adb kill-server" and restart the ADB daemon, it cannot find the device any more unless I re-plugin the device.

Since we're trying to setup test automation we cannot manually re-plug it manually every time, so is there any programatic way to allow reload ADB daemon and re-recognize the device? I'm running CI tools on a Mac Mini.

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: We are using command line to control the test flow. No IDE involved.

Answer (score 0):

It turn out to be something not so deterministic. I tried "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" before but no affection, so I posted a question here. But some time later I ran "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" again and it shows my device connected properly.

I haven't figure out why but I can say try it more times, eventually device would be recognised even not it hasn't been re-plugged-in to server. Anyone who knows why please share us some insight. thanks.